# How can i connect my next.js 13 project with Mongodb locally

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I want to connect my next.js 13 project to mongodb locally for practice how can i do it?

I tried to search about this but i couldn't find way for solving this problem

If you have a way to solving this problem please say to me

Answer (score 0):

Check the official docs: [https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/connections/connection-guide/#:~:text=If%20your%20MongoDB%20Server%20is,Manual%20entry%20on%20Connection%20Strings](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/connections/connection-guide/#:%7E:text=If%20your%20MongoDB%20Server%20is,Manual%20entry%20on%20Connection%20Strings).

> After you successfully start your MongoDB server, specify your connection string in your driver connection code.

> If your MongoDB Server is running locally, you can use the connection string "mongodb://localhost:" where  is the port number you configured your server to listen for incoming connections.